# Total IIS server giving Internal server 500 error

Tags: iis

I have an IIS server 7.5 . So it's run fine up to yesterday. suddenly all services/sites are not working. Total sites in the server are giving common error as

```
Internal Server Error : 500
```

This issue is with all websites hosted on that server.

could somebody show me some route to solve this issue ?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the Event Viewer and the log files to see if there is some issue being reported? Any further information you can supply? Otherwise this question is probably not answerable as-is.

Comment: In the Event viewer all i can see are some warning about .Net Frame work

Comment: Geee - It would be useful to know what the warning actually said so we can determine if it's relevant...

Comment: @RB. I have updated with image , hope that may help

Comment: That's much better - the error is right there in the image! "There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined" in the web.config of your web-application. This is preventing your application starting up. Remove the duplicate section and you should be ok.

Comment: @RB. thank you , this is not for one single website. Total IIS websites are turned like this. upto yesterday all are fine. But suddenly something changed and we are in this issue.

Comment: Maybe it's changed in the machine.config (which is the base for all your web.configs)?

Comment: Have you changed anything with the application pool or .net installation on the server? 500 errors can sometimes be attributed to that.

Comment: Have you actually checked the `web.config` for the site which this error was produced to verify that there are *not* duplicate `scriptResourceHandler`??

Comment: @m1Lb4nKs this error is not for one single website. total websites in that server all behaving same

Comment: Regardless, you shouldn't rule things out a priori. IIS is telling you specifically what is wrong, why in the world wouldn't you just check the `web.config` files?